# Undefined symbols that sure should be defined in GNU Radio libraries I'm linking to

Tags: c++, gnuradio

I've been attempting to port [an old utility](https://github.com/csm/gr-scan) to GNU Radio 3.9/3.10. Linking the program results in many undefined symbol errors, for symbols that are in the shared libraries being linked. I can't figure out what I'm missing, and nothing I've tried has helped.

[This issue](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/1045) sounds familiar to what I'm seeing (and I did see undefined symbols related to log4cpp, which went away when I added `-llog4cpp` to the linker flags). I assume what I'm missing is something by extending GNU Radio classes with the classes here, but I can't tell what.

The error message in all its glory:

```
g++ -DVERSION="\"gr-scan 2013102901\"" -I/usr/local/include  -Wall -g -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-function -c -o main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:22:
arguments.hpp: In member function ‘error_t Arguments::parse_opt(int, char*, argp_state*)’:
arguments.hpp:168:6: warning: this ‘if’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  168 |      if (outcsv_writeheader)
      |      ^~
arguments.hpp:170:7: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘if’
  170 |       fflush(outcsv);
      |       ^~~~~~
g++ -DVERSION="\"gr-scan 2013102901\"" -I/usr/local/include  -Wall -g -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-function -c -o scanner_sink.o scanner_sink.cpp
g++ -DVERSION="\"gr-scan 2013102901\"" -I/usr/local/include  -Wall -g -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-function -c -o topblock.o topblock.cpp
g++ -DVERSION="\"gr-scan 2013102901\"" -I/usr/local/include  -Wall -g -std=c++11 -Wno-unused-function -lstdc++ -llog4cpp -lboost_system -lgnuradio-blocks -lgnuradio-pmt -lgnuradio-fft -lgnuradio-osmosdr -lgnuradio-runtime -lpython3.8 -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o gr-scan main.o scanner_sink.o topblock.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/main.cpp:42: undefined reference to `gr::top_block::run(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o: in function `scanner_sink::scanner_sink(std::shared_ptr<osmosdr::source>, unsigned int, double, double, double, double, double, double, unsigned int, double, double, double, _IO_FILE*)':
/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:40: undefined reference to `gr::buffer_double_mapped::type'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:40: undefined reference to `gr::io_signature::make(int, int, int, gr::buffer_type_base const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:39: undefined reference to `gr::buffer_double_mapped::type'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:39: undefined reference to `gr::io_signature::make(int, int, int, gr::buffer_type_base const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:57: undefined reference to `gr::block::block(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<gr::io_signature>, std::shared_ptr<gr::io_signature>)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:57: undefined reference to `gr::block::~block()'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o: in function `scanner_sink::~scanner_sink()':
/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:62: undefined reference to `gr::block::~block()'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o: in function `scanner_sink::general_work(int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, std::vector<void const*, std::allocator<void const*> >&, std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> >&)':
/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/scanner_sink.cpp:80: undefined reference to `gr::block::consume_each(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o: in function `pmt::comparator::operator()(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&) const':
/usr/include/pmt/pmt.h:976: undefined reference to `pmt::eqv(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o: in function `gr::msg_queue_comparator::operator()(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&) const':
/usr/include/gnuradio/basic_block.h:39: undefined reference to `pmt::eqv(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/include/gnuradio/basic_block.h:41: undefined reference to `pmt::eqv(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o: in function `gr::basic_block::has_msg_port(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>)':
/usr/include/gnuradio/basic_block.h:311: undefined reference to `pmt::dict_has_key(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0x20): undefined reference to `gr::msg_accepter::post(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0x68): undefined reference to `gr::block::set_processor_affinity(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0x70): undefined reference to `gr::block::unset_processor_affinity()'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0x80): undefined reference to `gr::block::set_log_level(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0x88): undefined reference to `gr::block::log_level[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0x90): undefined reference to `gr::block::forecast(int, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0xa0): undefined reference to `gr::block::start()'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0xa8): undefined reference to `gr::block::stop()'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0xb0): undefined reference to `gr::block::fixed_rate_ninput_to_noutput(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV12scanner_sink[_ZTV12scanner_sink]+0xb8): undefined reference to `gr::block::fixed_rate_noutput_to_ninput(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: scanner_sink.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI12scanner_sink[_ZTI12scanner_sink]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for gr::block'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o: in function `TopBlock::TopBlock(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, unsigned int, double, double, double, _IO_FILE*)':
/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `gr::top_block::top_block(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `osmosdr::source::make(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `gr::blocks::stream_to_vector::make(unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `gr::fft::fft_v<double, true>::make(int, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> > const&, bool, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `gr::blocks::complex_to_mag_squared::make(unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `gr::filter::single_pole_iir_filter_ff::make(double, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `gr::blocks::nlog10_ff::make(float, unsigned long, float)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:57: undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::connect(std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int, std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:58: undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::connect(std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int, std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:59: undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::connect(std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int, std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:60: undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::connect(std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int, std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:61: undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::connect(std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int, std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:62: more undefined references to `gr::hier_block2::connect(std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int, std::shared_ptr<gr::basic_block>, int)' follow
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o: in function `TopBlock::TopBlock(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, unsigned int, double, double, double, _IO_FILE*)':
/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:46: undefined reference to `gr::top_block::~top_block()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o: in function `TopBlock::~TopBlock()':
/home/atuonuc/src/gr-scan/topblock.cpp:65: undefined reference to `gr::top_block::~top_block()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o: in function `gr::hier_block2::message_port_is_hier_in(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>)':
/usr/include/gnuradio/hier_block2.h:218: undefined reference to `pmt::list_has(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o: in function `gr::hier_block2::message_port_is_hier_out(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>)':
/usr/include/gnuradio/hier_block2.h:223: undefined reference to `pmt::list_has(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x20): undefined reference to `gr::msg_accepter::post(std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>, std::shared_ptr<pmt::pmt_base>)'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x58): undefined reference to `gr::top_block::setup_rpc()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x68): undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::set_processor_affinity(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x70): undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::unset_processor_affinity()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x78): undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::processor_affinity()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x80): undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::set_log_level(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x88): undefined reference to `gr::hier_block2::log_level[abi:cxx11]()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x90): undefined reference to `gr::top_block::lock()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV8TopBlock[_ZTV8TopBlock]+0x98): undefined reference to `gr::top_block::unlock()'
/usr/bin/ld: topblock.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTI8TopBlock[_ZTI8TopBlock]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for gr::top_block'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:24: gr-scan] Error 1
```

I've made an [issue on my fork of this program](https://github.com/csm/gr-scan/issues/1). I'm running this on Ubuntu 20.04, on an Intel NUC system. I've got the official GNU Radio 3.10.4 packages installed.

So, what basic C++ thing am I missing here?

Comment: Order of libraries on the command line matter! Always put libraries *last*, after the object files that uses the libraries.

Comment: It's a crazy Linux thing not a C++ thing.

Comment: That works! That's great! That sucks!